# Can entities as users exist without being tied to nodes

Tags: users, entities

Can entities as users exist without being tied to nodes, I'm starting a site that I don't want a lot of overhead and it will have a lot of users and they will be contacting each other often.

Comment: You did not specify your Drupal version. Users were never "tied" to nodes in Drupal core, however there was a Usernode module for Drupal 6 that made users into nodes.

Answer (score 1):

In D7 Users are an Entity type, they are their own Entity type. A Node is another entity type with various bundles such as Page, Article, etc.

Taxonomy is another example of an Entity.

An Entity does not necessarily mean a "Node" in drupal 7.

See this [introduction to Drupal 7 Entities](http://drupal.org/node/1261744) on drupal.org